# How to combine fixture with parametrize

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing, pytest-fixtures

I have comfortably been using `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` in many tests now. I have not, however, succeeded in combining it with `@pytest.fixture()` and I cannot find a question answering this issue.

This example applies `@pytest.fixture()` succesfully (copied from another question that I cannot find anymore):

```
import pytest
def foo(data, key):
    return data[key]

@pytest.fixture()
def dict_used_by_many_tests():
    return {"name": "Dionysia", "age": 28, "location": "Athens"}

def test_foo_one(dict_used_by_many_tests):
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "name")
    expected = "Dionysia"
    assert actual == expected
```

Now, in practice I want to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize()`.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def dict_used_by_many_tests():
    return {"name": "Dionysia", "age": 28, "location": "Athens"}

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "dict_used_by_many_tests",
    [
        (dict_used_by_many_tests),
    ],
)
def test_foo_one(dict_used_by_many_tests):
    actual = foo(dict_used_by_many_tests, "name")
    expected = "Dionysia"
    assert actual == expected
```

This results in the error: `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`.

I tried calling `dict_used_by_many_tests()` to work with its return value instead of the function object. This resulted in a `Fixtures are not meant to be called directly` error, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is [`request.getfixturevalue`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue):

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def dict_used_by_many_tests():
    return {
        "name": "Dionysia",
        "age": 28,
        "location": "Athens",
    }


@pytest.fixture()
def dict_used_by_some_tests():
    return {
        "name": "Medusa, maybe?",
        "age": 2 << 32,
        "location": "Underworld?",
    }


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fixture_name",
    [
        "dict_used_by_many_tests",
        "dict_used_by_some_tests",
    ],
)
def test_foo_one(request, fixture_name):
    d = request.getfixturevalue(fixture_name)
    # ...
```

Another is [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization):

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def character_dict(request):
    if request.param == 1:
        return {"name": "Dionysia", "age": 28, "location": "Athens"}
    elif request.param == 2:
        return {"name": "Medusa", "age": 2 << 32, "location": "Underworld"}
    raise NotImplementedError(f"No such dict: {request.param!r}")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "character_dict",
    [1, 2],
    indirect=True,
)
def test_foo_one(character_dict):
    assert isinstance(character_dict, dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the recommended pytest pattern is to work with `pytest.fixture(params=...)`:

```py
import pytest

params = ["arthur", "liz", "buddy"]

@pytest.fixture(params=params)
def person(request):
    name = request.param
    return {"name": name, "age": 5}

def test_persons(person):
    assert isinstance(person["name"], str)
    assert person["age"] == 5
```

You can find more information on this in the pytest documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/fixtures.html#parametrizing-fixtures

Comment: Have you tried running this code? I get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when it tries to execute person().

Comment: Thanks, indeed! I accidentally kept the parentheses after `request.param`, when I copied from a piece of code I wrote a while ago, where the parameters where classes to be instantiated. I corrected the example now.